# Why is sleep needed after fabric call to pg_ctl restart

Tags: postgresql, sleep, fabric

I'm using Fabric to initialize a postgres server.  I have to add a "sleep 1" at the end of the command or the postgres server processes die without explanation or an entry in the log:

```
sudo('%(pgbin)s/pg_ctl -D %(pgdata)s -l /tmp/pg.log restart && sleep 1' % env, user='postgres')
```

That is, I see this output on the terminal:

> [dbserv] Executing task 'setup_postgres' 
>   [dbserv] run: /bin/bash -l -c "sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl -D /data/pg -l /tmp/pg.log restart && sleep 1"
>   [dbserv] out: waiting for server to shut down.... done
>   [dbserv] out: server stopped
>   [dbserv] out: server starting

Without the `&& sleep 1`, there's nothing in /tmp/pg.log (though the file is created), and no postgres processes are running.  With the sleep, everything works fine.

(And if I execute the same command directly on target machine's command line, it works fine without the sleep.)

Since it's working, it doesn't *really* matter, but I'm asking anyway:  Does someone know what the sleep is allowing to happen and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try also using the [pty option](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work) set it to false and see if it's related to how fabric handles pseudo-ttys.

Comment: Yeah, that works in place of the sleep.  I'd up vote it, but I lack the reputation.

Comment: I hate that part of this site actually. Does it also keep you from accepting too? It's weird how the functionality forces new users to only be able to ask questions, instead of ask/answer.

Comment: IMHO, it doesn't * really * answer the question since it doesn't say what's going on under the hood, but if there are no other replies in a few days, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: You say new users can't answer questions? That's news to me.

Comment: The reputation part of the FAQ,  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation, mentions needing points to upvote, etc. But looking at that, answering is allowed, but commenting before one has 50 reputation (on questions not their own) isn't allowed.